# Fatal error uncaught error call to a member function get_price() on null on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am using Flatsome theme with WooCommerce and I am working on WooCommerce API calls.

For Orders and Customers, it is working perfectly.

However, I get this error for Products:

> fatal error uncaught error call to a member function get_price() on null in
> home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/inc/wc-products-functions.php 1046.

I have added the following code in this file location:
/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome/woocommerce/single-product/price.php.

I have added the following code in this file: themes/flatsome/woocommerce/single-product/price.php file

```
<?php
function sv_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    global $product;
    $price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); 
    $price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );  
    <p class="price">Ex. VAT:<?php echo wc_price( $price_excl_tax ); ?>
    <p class="price-incl">Incl. VAT: <?php echo wc_price( $price_incl_tax ); ?>
    <?php 
    //return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_price_display' );
```

I have added this code functions.php files:

```
<?php
function sv_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    global $product;
    $price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); 
    $price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );  
    <p class="price">Ex. VAT:<?php echo wc_price( $price_excl_tax ); ?>
    <p class="price-incl">Incl. VAT: <?php echo wc_price( $price_incl_tax ); ?>
    <?php 
    //return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_price_display' );
```

What I am doing wrong?